# Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : Failure when receiving data from the peer

Tags: r, loops, rcurl, httr

I'm trying to get lyrics from the [chartlyrics API](http://www.chartlyrics.com/). I write an R function that works but not inside a loop. My script is:

```
library(httr)
library(RCurl)
library(XML)

df <- data.frame(artist = c('Led Zeppellin', 'Adele'), song = c('Rock´n roll', 'Hello'), stringsAsFactors = F)

make.querye <- function(xx) {
  names_ok <- gsub(" ", "&", xx)
  names_ok2 <- paste("\'", names_ok, "\'", sep = '')
 querye <- paste("http://api.chartlyrics.com/apiv1.asmx/SearchLyricDirect?artist=", names_ok[1],"&song=",  names_ok[2], sep='')
 data <- GET(querye)
 aa <- content(data, "text")   
 doc <- htmlParse(aa, asText=TRUE)  
 plain.text <- xpathSApply(doc, "//lyric//text()[not(ancestor::script)][not(ancestor::style)][not(ancestor::noscript)][not(ancestor::form)]", xmlValue)  
 if (length(plain.text)==0) {
   plain.text2 <- 'Lyrics not found'
 } else {
   plain.text2 <- iconv(plain.text, from = "UTF-8", to = "latin1", sub = NA, mark = TRUE, toRaw = FALSE)  
 }
 return(plain.text2)
 }


names <- c(df$artist[1], df$song[1])
make.querye(names) #- it works

names <- c(df$artist[2], df$song[2])
make.querye(names) #- it also works
```

But my function doesn't work inside a loop

```
for (ii in  1:2){
  names <- c(df$artist[ii], df$song[ii])
  print(names)
  make.querye(names)
}
```

I get the following error:

> Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : Failure when receiving data from the peer

Comment: are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Sorry, I have seen today your comment. In fact I'm not sure about your question. Is a really old question and now I'm not working on this, then I'm going to close the question (if I can because never did it before). In this long period I have seen other doing the a similar thing and I thoght that the solution is to put some time between request, but I'm not sure about this. Anyway, thanks for your answer

Answer (score 5):

The `RETRY` function was introduced in [June 2016](https://github.com/r-lib/httr/releases/tag/v1.2.0) and allows you to retry a request multiple times until it succeeds.

Use it with the parameter `verb = "GET"` instead of directly using `GET`, i.e.,

```
data <- RETRY("GET", query)
```

You can also define the maximum number of attempts with the `times` parameter.